# Expecting $end after first input

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use flex and bison to build a simple parser for a programming language.

When I was testing it from terminal(stdin), it always says that (the `yyerror()` is customized):

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected SOME_TOKEN, expecting $end, on line: 2
```

on the second input. In another word, it only works well on the first input.

I can only guess that the internal parse stack of bison didn't flush after the first statement.

Here is my bison code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define YYDEBUG 1
%}

%token TOKEN_DECLARE TOKEN_SET TOKEN_STR TOKEN_SYMBOL EOL
%error-verbose

%%

statement: statement
    | declare_var EOL { puts("Reach declare EOL branch"); }
    | set_value EOL { puts("Reach set_value EOL branch"); }

;

declare_var: TOKEN_DECLARE TOKEN_SYMBOL { printf("Declare var\n"); }
        | TOKEN_DECLARE set_value
;

set_value : TOKEN_SYMBOL TOKEN_SET { printf("Set var"); }
        | set_value TOKEN_STR { printf(" to string\n"); }
        | set_value TOKEN_SYMBOL { printf(" to symbol\n"); }
;

%%
```

Here is my flex code

```
%%
[\t\n ] {/*Ignore*/}

var {
    return (TOKEN_DECLARE);
}

";" {
    //puts("Got EOL");
    return (EOL);
}

\"[a-zA-Z]+\" {
    return (TOKEN_STR);
} 
\'[a-zA-Z]+\' {
    return (TOKEN_STR);
}

[a-zA-Z]+ {
    return (TOKEN_SYMBOL);
}

"=" {
    return (TOKEN_SET);
}
%%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your yacc code only accepts a single statement -- after the `EOL` the only valid token is `$end` (end of file/input), so you get a syntax error on the second line.  Also, the rule `statement: statement` is useless and can never be reduced (you should be getting an error message from yacc about it).

What you want is an explicit rule for matching multiple statements:

```
statements: statements statement
          | statement
;
```

which is the first (start) rule.  Then your statement rule is just:

```
statement: declare_var EOL { puts("Reach declare EOL branch"); }
         | set_value EOL { puts("Reach set_value EOL branch"); }
;
```